# Calculate difference between current time and next failure in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset where one of the columns contains if there was a failure or not represented by 0 and 1. I need to create a new columns which contains time to next failure in pandas.

[image: Like this]

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) with swapped values by indexing with `[::-1]` for groups passed to function [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'failure': [0,0,0,1,0,0,1]})

s = df['failure'].iloc[::-1].cumsum()
df['time to failure'] = s.groupby(s).cumcount()
print (df)
   failure  time to failure
0        0                3
1        0                2
2        0                1
3        1                0
4        0                2
5        0                1
6        1                0
```

Comment: Took me quite a while to understand this, Thankyou.This answers my problem.

Comment: @HariomSingh - Btw, small friend advice - dont use pictures with sample data or code in question, [link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)